# AJAX call success but throws Undefined index error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, google-api

I have an ajax call that passes data to another php file, createTest2.php, as below.

But the createTest2.php file throws error

"Notice: Undefined index: aaa in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestProj\Test\createTest2.php on line 2

caller.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button_submit").click(function() 
  {

    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"createTest2.php",
      data:{aaa : "UNIT_TEST"},
      success:function()
      {
        alert("success");
      }
    });
 });
});
```

createTest2.php

```
$test_name = $_POST['aaa'];
```

Comment: on similiar questions, for the same issues, everyone used `aaa` as the param.... lol.

Answer (score 3):

there is nothing wrong on your code/script. i tried it on my localhost and it works.

make sure that the error reporting is configured correctly because it is printing a notice
that will also be passed to your ajax result.

to remove it use these on top of php code of your `createTest2.php`:
(before you call anything, just after the first php opening tag)

```
<?php
ini_set("DISPLAY_ERRORS",0);
error_reporting(0);
```

take note that it is only a `NOTICE` and not an `ERROR` as indicated on your question.
hope that helps. ;)

** UPDATE: some people say it is recommended to fix the notices instead of just hiding them, just so you know..

Answer (score 1):

Give data attribute in quotes,

*Change*

```
 data:{aaa : "UNIT_TEST"},
```

*To*

```
data:{"aaa" : "UNIT_TEST"},
```

Comment: that *really* shouldn't matter considering it's an object, and object keys don't have to be wrapped in quotes unless they contain spaces or operators.

Comment: Changed it. Still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to send is as an data query ( using param to convert object to an data query)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button_submit").click(function() 
  {
    var params = $.param({aaa : "UNIT_TEST"});

    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"createTest2.php",
      data: params,
      success:function()
      {
        alert("success");
      }
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: changed. Still same problem.